# how to change the onclick javascript button to lightning component?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, button

can any one help in changing the onclick javascript button to lightning component?..becasuse javascript button are not supported in lightning.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")}

var Suite = '{!Contract__C.Suite__c}';
var check = '{!Contract__C.Notification_check__c}';
var amount= '{!Contract__C.amount__c}';
var blackReview = '{!Contract__C.black_Review__c}';

var blackReview= blackReview!= '' && blackReview!= 'No';
var Suite = Suite != '';
var amount= Number(amount.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
amount = amount>=1000.00;
//alert(blackReview+" "+ amount+" " +Suite );

if ((amount|| blackReview|| Suite)&& check == 0){
var con= new sforce.SObject("Contract__C");
con.id = "{!Contract__C.Id}";
con.Notification_check__c = 1;
result = sforce.connection.update([con]);
}
```

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cGX8AAM

Comment: see also [Trailhead Javascript button LEX migration](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/module/lex_javascript_button_migration)